# Assignment Operators in C

Tags: c, operators, variable-assignment

**When i run this code everything is fine but the value of a /= 10; output is 10 and 10 is wrong answer right answer is 1.**

```
// C program to demonstrate 
// working of Assignment operators 

#include <stdio.h> 

int main() 
{ 

    // Assigning value 10 to a 
    // using "=" operator 
    int a = 10; 
    printf("Value of a is %d\n", a); 

    // Assigning value by adding 10 to a 
    // using "+=" operator 
    a += 10; 
    printf("Value of a is %d\n", a); 

    // Assigning value by subtracting 10 from a 
    // using "-=" operator 
    a -= 10; 
    printf("Value of a is %d\n", a); 

    // Assigning value by multiplying 10 to a 
    // using "*=" operator 
    a *= 10; 
    printf("Value of a is %d\n", a); 

    // Assigning value by dividing 10 from a 
    // using "/=" operator 
    a /= 10; 
    printf("Value of a is %d\n", a); 

    return 0; 
}
```

But when i run this code

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() 
{ 

    int a = 10; 
    
    a /= 10; 
    printf("Value of a is %d\n", a); 

    return 0; 
}


**the output is 1 but how please help me.**
```

Comment: Why do you think it should be `1`? What does the `printf` output show as the value before the division?

Comment: `10/10` = what should be the outcome?

Comment: 100/10=10. Single step through the code with your favourite debugger.

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
// Assigning value by multiplying 10 to a 
// using "*=" operator 
a *= 10; 
printf("Value of a is %d\n", a); 

// Assigning value by dividing 10 from a 
// using "/=" operator 
a /= 10; 
printf("Value of a is %d\n", a); 

return 0;
```

returns 10 for the last operation, as the previous operation multiplies `a` by `10` and stores it back to `a`, so `a` is `100` when you perform the division `a /=10`. `100/10`, result is 10.